# Was it coincidence that Omar and Anna met?

Tags: zero

In the Italian series *Zero*, Omar met Anna when she ordered pizza from the restaurant that he worked for, and he walked into her apartment since no one was answering the door. He later discovers that her father is the developer who is planning to buy up his neighborhood, and who is paying people to commit acts of vandalism and thus devalue it.

In a city of over a million people, this seems like a fairly major coincidence. Is there any reason for this, or was it merely a chance encounter? There do seem to be some greater forces at play, after all.